# I'm looking for a dataset on enviroment monitoring

Tags: deep-learning, classification, dataset, data, data-analysis

I'm looking for a dataset related to environmental monitoring, made up of values obtained from various types of sensors (such as temperature, pressure, CO2...etc) for the purpose of a classification task. However, I'm not sure this is possible with any dataset, so I wanted to ask you if you had any suggestions for a dataset I could use.

Multimodal data (images and sensors) are also accepted and could be very useful.

Please let me know if you have any recommendations or potential sources. I've already looked through Google Datasets and Kaggle.

Comment: Hi @PiEmmeC, welcome to the site. If you don't get acceptable answers here, you may try also at https://opendata.stackexchange.com/